# Trouble installing Boost 1.58

Tags: 14.04, c++, boost

running 14.04 LTS. I've gone and actually deleted the Boost directory from my /usr/include directory. I'm still trying to figure out how exactly to install this and get it working with my application.

The version I'm trying to install is 1.58. I'm not seeing anything online to help with this exactly. How should I go about this?